# toggle() scope in a jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a skilltree composed by node containing an hidden description

the single node is like this

```
<div class="node inactive-node root">
    <a href="#">Example Skill</a>
    <div class="info">
    <p class="cost">30</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b></a>
           <div class="dropdown-menu">
               <a href="#">Example description</a>
           </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

the following script make obviusly show all the dropdown-menu in the page

```
var main = function() {     
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click( function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggle(); 
    });
};
```

but the fix i tried

```
var main = function() {     
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click( function() {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').toggle(); 
    });
};
```

is ineffective and i cant figure why.I'm tryng to select the single dropdown-menu under the clicked dropdown-toggle, but i'm failing to understand how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a child element.  It's a sibling.  Try using next().

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

Or

```
$(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('+.dropdown-menu',this).toggle();
```

Or

```
$('+.dropdown-menu',this).slideToggle();
```